# Cant make wsl2 working with on docker and on ubuntu

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

This is the list:

```
aaa@2UL:~$ wsl.exe --list --verbose
  NAME                   STATE           VERSION
* Ubuntu-20.04           Running         1 <------------note - this is version one
  docker-desktop-data    Running         2
  docker-desktop         Running         2
```

When I run `docker ps` in the bash I get:

```
The command 'docker' could not be found in this WSL 1 distro.
We recommend to convert this distro to WSL 2 and activate
the WSL integration in Docker Desktop settings.
```

In ubuntu I have the following settings:
[image]

This is my Windows info:

```
Edition Windows 10 Home
Version 21H1
Installed on    ‎10/‎07/‎2021
OS build    19043.928
Experience  Windows Feature Experience Pack 120.2212.551.0
```

This command has no effect: `wsl --set-default-version 2`

I want to be able to access docker from ubuntu, how is that possible?

**UPDATE**

When I run: `wsl.exe --set-version Ubuntu-20.04 2` Nothing happened. this is the output:

```
Conversion in progress, this may take a few minutes...
For information on key differences with WSL 2 please visit https://aka.ms/wsl2
The Windows Subsystem for Linux instance has terminated.
Press any key to continue...
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try:

`wsl.exe --set-version Ubuntu-20.04 2`

Make sure to run this command from Command prompt (CMD) or Powershell.

Comment: Will accept it soon. can you please also have a look here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1351156/how-to-locate-docker-drive-location-on-wsl2 ?
thanks