# How to locate docker drive location on WSL2

Tags: docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux

When I go to: `\\wsl$\docker-desktop-data\version-pack-data\community\docker\volumes` I can see my volumes.

But I want to see them from the Linux side, so I go to: `/mnt/wsl/docker-desktop-data/version-pack-data` it is empty.

Even as root.

How can I access my volume files from Linux?
Thanks

Comment: The volumes in `/mnt/wsl/docker-desktop-data/data/docker/volumes`. make sure to enter as Root.

Comment: Thanks, but `ls -la /mnt/wsl/docker-desktop-data/data/` is empty...

Answer (score 0):

Under Docker Desktop for Windows, with WSL2 integration, two special "instances" are created, which you can see with:

```
> wsl -l -v

  NAME                   STATE           VERSION
* Ubuntu                 Running         2
  docker-desktop         Stopped         2
  docker-desktop-data    Stopped         2
```

Local docker volumes (as well as images and other data) are kept in `docker-desktop-data`, probably to provide common access across any installed WSL2 instance (for which Docker integration has been enabled), as well as PowerShell.

Please see [this question and my answer there](https://superuser.com/q/1613589/1210833) for information on how to inspect that data.

Comment: I want to view it via ubuntu, so I go to: `/mnt/wsl/docker-desktop-data/version-pack-data` and it is empty. thankls